# I can't run this python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written some python code but this is not giving me any output please help me to solve.

```
def main():
    num1 = int(raw_input("Enter first number"))
    num2 = int(raw_input("Enter second number"))

    result = num1 + num2

    print result
```

Comment: Do you ever *call* that function? Add `main()` at the end. And see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: call the damn function to run it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't called the function that you have created.

This will work:

```
def main():
    num1 = int(raw_input("Enter first number"))
    num2 = int(raw_input("Enter second number"))

    result = num1 + num2

    print result

main()
```

If this doesn't work then you are probably using python3, in that case try this:

```
def main():
    num1 = input("Enter first number")
    num2 = input("Enter second number")

    result = num1 + num2

    print (result)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try calling the main() function:

```
def main():
    num1 = int(raw_input("Enter first number"))
    num2 = int(raw_input("Enter second number"))

    result = num1 + num2

    print result

main() # <-- calling main() function
```